# ActionBarSherlock Fragment with GridView - NullPointerException on CreateView

Tags: android, gridview, actionbarsherlock

Im currently trying to Make a GridView with ABS(ActionBarSherlock) within a FRAGMENT. But Im having some issue, getting NPE(NullPointerException). Here is my **Fragment** Code:

```
public class Fragment2 extends SherlockFragment {

GridView gridView;
ImageAdapter imgAdapter;
private Context context;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    context = getSherlockActivity();
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(context));

    return rootView;
}
```

**And my ImageAdapterClass:**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};

private static Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

}

And Finally my LogCat:

```
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at com.AlexPrograms.NavDrawerSherlock.Fragment2.onCreateView(Fragment2.java:24)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
10-25 01:06:32.239: E/AndroidRuntime(12344):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I wish my best if u can find what's wrong. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is this the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just get over ABS and when to ActionBar Compat with de Support Lib.

Here my fragmentClass.

```
public class FragmentCategories extends Fragment {

private GridView vGrid;
private Context vContenx;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View primalView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories_grid, container, false);

    vContenx = getActivity();

    vGrid = (GridView) primalView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    vGrid.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(vContenx));


    return primalView;
}
```

And the getView of my Adaptor for the GridView

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View gridView, ViewGroup fatherGroup) {

    catNames = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.value_Cats);

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView  textView;
    if (gridView == null) { 
        gridView = mlayoutPrinter.inflate(R.layout.grid_items, null);
        imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 120;

        textView =  (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.TextItem);
        textView.setText(catNames[pos]);
        gridView.setTag(imageView);
        textView.setTag(textView);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView)gridView.getTag();
    }


    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[pos]);


    return gridView;
}
```

And the XML for the fragment which contains a GridView

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/BandHookGrey"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentCategories" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="7dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="7dp"
    android:background="@color/BandHookGrey"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

And by Last the XML of the Layout that is inflated to populate the Grid.

```
<LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/GridItemImage"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#FFF"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/TextItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/gridText"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first things first. That fragment is not *properly designed*. ;)

This line:

```
context = getSherlockActivity();
```

Could be crashing.

The correct (preferred and standard) way to pass the context to a Fragment should be something along these lines:

```
public class YourFragment extends SherlockFragment  {
    private static Context sContext;
    public static YourFragment newInstance(Context context) {
        if (context != null) {
            sContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        } else {
            sContext = YourAppInstance.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
        }
        return new YourFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        init();
    }
    private void init() {
       // Add anything else you need (and can) init.
        if (sContext == null) {
            sContext = mApp.getApplicationContext();
        }

    }
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
            init(); // in case of a resume overnight where stuff may be null
    }
    // NOW YOUR STUFF
    private GridView mGridView;
    private ImageAdapter mImgAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
         mGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
         if ( mGridView != null && sContext != null ) {
             mImgAdapter = new ImageAdapter(sContext);
             mGridView.setAdapter(mImgAdapter);
         }

         return rootView;
    }  
}
```

That looks more Androidish…

Now, before using getSherlockActivity() inside fragments, it's recommended to do a

```
if (getSherlockActivity() != null && !getSherlockActivity().isFinishing() ) {
   //Safe to use getSherlockActivity here
}
```

And last but not least…

your ImageAdapter…

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
```

is returning null, so the grid has all null items…

Maybe you meant something like…

```
  public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position]
  }
```

I mean, your image adapter is an adapter of what exactly? references to images? It's kind of weird because it's hardcoded, but you must return something, remember that the Grid will ask its adapter for views and the adapter needs to find the data to create that view.